# How can i add class for div inside of javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

guys I need to add a class for div inside of a javascript function. I wanna put a box every a`gency_name`, `ADRESS_TEXT` and  `phone`  How can I do this

```
  function jsFilt(value) {
                   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
                    value.AGENCY.forEach(agency => {
                        $("#myDiv").append(
                       //HERE     "<div class ="xxx" style='border-style:ridge' ><strong>Agency Name :</strong>  " + agency.agency_name + "<br>" +
                            "<strong>Adress : </strong> " + agency.ADRESS_TEXT + "<br> "+
                            "<strong>Phone :</strong>  " + agency.phone + "<br></div>"
                        );
                    });
                }
```

CSS

```
.xxx{
    width: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: you are already using JQuery you can use addClass() https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

Comment: what do you mean beforeappend ?  $("#myDiv").addClass("xx").append

Comment: did you tired $("#myDiv").append(....).addClass("xx")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said there is two ways: `.addClass('classname1 classname2')` and `.attr('class','classname1 classname2')` but `addClass` is better

in your case will be like:

```
function jsFilt(value) {
  console.log('running jsFilt');
  //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
  $('#myDiv').html(''); // this is jquery way of doing it
  console.log('myDiv is now empty');

  value.AGENCY.forEach(agency => {
    console.log('inside loop');
        //first we create that div and give it class and style
        const $div = $('<div></div>').addClass('xxx').attr('style','border-style:ridge;');
        // here we set innerHTML
        $div.html(`
            <strong>Agency Name :</strong>  ` + agency.agency_name + `<br>
            <strong>Adress : </strong> ` + agency.ADRESS_TEXT + `<br>  
            <strong>Phone :</strong> ` + agency.phone + `<br>
        `);

        console.log('here is the div we created:',$div);

        // here we append it to the container (#myDiv)
        $("#myDiv").append($div);
        console.log('this is how myDiv looks like now', $("#myDiv"));
    });
}
```

make sure you call the function of course `jsFilt(someValue)`

I put some `console.log('bla bla')` in my codes if you open browser console you can see some messages being printed out and it helps you track issue. after everything worked you can remove `console.log()`s

So this may work or may have some syntax errors. Let me know if you could get it to work

Comment: im not get any error but i think my  class(xxx) is not worked not change anything sir

Comment: please give me some examples. like example htmls which you want the javascript to produce. and are you sure you call the function? `jsFilt(value)`? and you can put flags to see if each part of code gets executed. Ill update my answer

Comment: yeap `jsFilt(value)` , `agency.agency_name` , `agency.ADRESS_TEXT` and `agency.phone` i get  all of them

Comment: so then what is your problem now?

Comment: as i say my class(xxx) is not worked not change anything looks like i can not add class

Comment: sorry cant help you much this way. I should have full codes so i can track issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can addClass to the div after the append like:

```
    function jsFilt(value) {
                   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
                    value.AGENCY.forEach(agency => {
                        $("#myDiv").append(
                            "<strong>Adress : </strong> " + agency.ADRESS_TEXT + "<br> "+
                            "<strong>Phone :</strong>  " + agency.phone + "<br></div>"
                        ).addClass("CLASSNAME1 CLASSNAME2");
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Hey there. I think your solution is not what he wants. as you are adding the class to the `myDiv` not the inner div which he wants. also you are adding the same class over and over (inside loop) to the container. you may want to check my answer.

Comment: True that, and yes my code would add it to `myDiv` and i like your answer. Thank you, its a lovely community here and i've got so much help from here i wanted to see if i can chime in.

Comment: Cool. I like your attitude. We need people like you here. Im same as you everyone is same as you. we have questions and problems we cant solve we ask. We see there is a problem we can help solve we jump in. have a nice day